# Array from Structure

Tags: ruby, json, coldfusion

I have a query which returns

```
 {
  "i-22beb65b": {
    "columns": ["time_stamp","stats_value"],
    "data":[
      [42296,2310],
      [42297,2380],
      [42298,2356],
      [42299,1972],
      [42300,4058],
      [42301,4168],
      [42302,2882],
      [42303,2256],
      [42304,1652],
      [42305,1422],
      [42306,2144],
      [42307,1344],
      [42308,2536],
      [42309,3096],
      [42310,2618],
      [42311,3276]
    ]
  },
  "i-9c8999e5": {
    "columns":["time_stamp","stats_value"],
    "data": [
      [42296,3674],
      [42297,3474],
      [42298,3662],
      [42299,3680],
      [42300,4376],
      [42301,2892],
      [42302,3480],
      [42303,4082],
      [42304,3936],
      [42305,3802],
      [42306,4260],
      [42307,3897],
      [42308,3393],
      [42309,4177],
      [42310,3975],
      [42311,4130]
    ]
  },
  "multi": {
    "columns":["time_stamp","stats_value"],
    "data":[]
  }
}
```

Please, how do i run a query on this results to have something like

```
"i-22beb65b":[[42296,3674],[42307,3897]]
"i-9c8999e5":[[42305,1422],[42306,2144]]
```

Basically i want to use the information to generate a Flot graph, which only accepts arrays, so im looking for a way to split the above to using something like my example so i can easily pass to Flot

Comment: What is the logic behind your selection from the data array?

Comment: I want to plot a graph using flot, which would be per value in ""

Comment: That's okay. My question was about how did you select those values from the data, there are more `time_stamp` and `stats_value` item for every key than what you expect in the results.

Comment: NO, its exactly what i wanted, but this is in a format that cant be used by Flot, because flot only accepts array of arrays, so im trying to see how i can split the above to array of arrays based on the key, though im using coldfusion in trying to achieve this

Comment: The outermost data structure in your desired result still is a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood it correctly, but if you only want to redefine your results query, you can do this:

```
data = {"i-22beb65b":{"columns":["time_stamp","stats_value"],"data":[[42296,2310],[42297,2380],[42298,2356],[42299,1972],[42300,4058],[42301,4168],[42302,2882],[42303,2256],[42304,1652],[42305,1422],[42306,2144],[42307,1344],[42308,2536],[42309,3096],[42310,2618],[42311,3276]]},"i-9c8999e5":{"columns":["time_stamp","stats_value"],"data":[[42296,3674],[42297,3474],[42298,3662],[42299,3680],[42300,4376],[42301,2892],[42302,3480],[42303,4082],[42304,3936],[42305,3802],[42306,4260],[42307,3897],[42308,3393],[42309,4177],[42310,3975],[42311,4130]]},"multi":{"columns":["time_stamp","stats_value"],"data":[]}}
data.map{|k,v| {k: v["data"]}}
```